# UINavigationBar frame height returns 44.0 but is actually 64.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I have a UINavigationController in a storyboard which is not using AutoLayout.  With the status bar visible the actual height of the UINavigationBar is 64.0 and yet when I log `self.navigationBar.frame.size.height` I get 44.0.  How do I get the actual height of the UINavigationBar?

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and the storyboard builds for iOS 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The height of the `UINavigationBar` is **44**. The reason you´re getting **64** is because of your status bar is visible and it has a height of **20**.

**Update:**
To calculate the height you could:

```
let height = Double(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height) + Double(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)
```

Comment: Is there a way to programtically get the visible height of the UINavigationBar i.e. 64.0 in that case?

Comment: @matteok, check the update, maybe something like that.

Comment: I just checked and the statusBar frame is 0.0 if the statusbar is hidden so i think checking for isStatusBar hidden is unnecessary. navigationBar.height + statusBarHeight should do the trick in both cases. If you agree you can edit your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Indeed, no need to do the check added it to make it clearer. Updated the answer @matteok.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use magic numbers. Use the view controller's `topLayoutGuide.length` to get the correct height. Navigation bar height and status bar height can change during runtime, so run your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to always use the correct value.

Comment: This only works when AutoLayout is enabled as far as I know

Comment: That's not true, layout guides are set correctly regardless of autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to just care of the navigationBar position and height and not assume there is a status bar over it. (As a matter of fact if the phone orientation is landscape there won't even be a status bar.
Just do this:

```
let height = Double(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.origin.y) + Double(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)
```