# Fix UILabel position below UITableViewController's UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

We are placing a temporary label over our UITableViewController `view` when we need to show a status message.  The view goes directly beneath the UINavigationBar.  This works well but the `statusView` scrolls with the table and will disappear as the table scrolls up.  How can you fix the statusView position even as the table scrolls?

**Update**:

What almost works as inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537858/ios-place-uiview-on-top-of-uitableview-in-fixed-position) is to use the TableViewDelegate method to fix the statusView position:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var newFrame = statusView.frame
    newFrame.origin.x = 0
    newFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height 
    statusView.frame = newFrame
}
```

It places our `statusView` bar in a fixed position but it's partially underneath the navigation bar.   Seems like we just need to tweak the `newFrame.origin.y` logic....

**Update 2**:

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/40202931/47281 just needed to include the status bar:

```
    newFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Comment: Is this status view required in particular table cell? If so, why can't you add it to the cell's view instead? Can you share a screenshot perhaps and more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per updates above solution was inspired by [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537858/ios-place-uiview-on-top-of-uitableview-in-fixed-position) - we used the TableViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll to fix the position:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var newFrame = statusView.frame
    newFrame.origin.x = 0
    newFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height 
    statusView.frame = newFrame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a ViewController subclass and add a UITableView to it instead of subclassing UITableViewController.